# Excel Userform - Order Form

Tags: excel, vba, userform

I have an Excel Userform. This user form is an order where there is 1 item ordered or 10 items ordered.

Sheet snippet

[image]

I want to store the items from the userform on a row in a sheet, for tracking purposes.  If you see the picture first there are words where is says "concepto" from there to the end, all the order will contain these columns these items are all needed for the each item ordered.

Sample View of Finished Product

[image]

should this be done in Access instead?  Or can it be done in Excel?

Sample of userform

[image]

Comment: It can be done in Excel, but I would recommend using an actual Microsoft FORM instead of trying to create one with VBA. That's just my commentary though. Google Sheets would be more first choice for a project like this.

Comment: thank you for your comment will contemplate and rethink my project to Goole Sheets.